# How to find the previous year particular month sale is higher or not compared to the same month of current year in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have Sales Table with the following fields.

```
year
month
samount
```

Requirement is to check if current month's sales amount is higher than the previous year sales amount for the same month.

I tried with the following sql but seems to be missing some comparison. Please advise

```
select year, month, samount, samount-lag(samount,12) over (order by year,month) as diff_cur_prev_sales from sales;
```

Comment: I have removed the Oracle tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare the same months sales with different years, You need to change your LAG function. Simply reverse the order of year and month column -

```
SELECT year, month, samount, prev_year_amount
  FROM (SELECT year, month, samount, lag(samount,12) over (order by month, year) as prev_year_amount 
          FROM sales
       ) T
 WHERE samount > prev_year_amount;
```

Comment: @ Ankit Bajpai - Thanks for the reply. Can you please help me to check the current year current month sales is higher to previous year same month sales or not with the above sql

Comment: @SNS, Try the updated query.

Comment: This works if I try to check if the sales amount matching or not between years. But the requirement is to get those records where the particular month sales is greater than last year month sales

Comment: @SNS, Please try the edited query.